# Why my device isn't supported?

Tags: android, google-play

I have just developed an app using ionic and uploaded to the play store as beta testing. However, the list show up to be only support 310 devices, which is totally unacceptable. So, I change the plugin I am using and re-submit it. This time, I am getting 9072 devices supported and my device is also listed.

But why is that when I check in the play store again, it still showing my device is not compatible?

Comment: How long did you wait? It can take several hours for changes you publish to become visible.

Comment: google takes 5-6 working hours to update old apk with new apk... wait for few hours than check

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your comment. But up until now play store still showing my device is not compatible.